# Расширение для Visual Studio 2013: добавление кнопки в стандартное (контекстное) меню

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions

Как добавить дополнительную кнопку в стандартное контекстное меню, которое появляется при щелчке правой кнопкой мыши рядом с кодом?

Например такая функциональность:

- правый щелчок вызывает стандартное меню
- в меню помимо стандартных есть новая кнопка
- щелчок по ней вызывает действие (например появляется сообщение)

Comment: переформулируйте заголовок и сам вопрос так, чтобы было понятно, что вам нужно именно добавить кнопку в меню, по которой произойдет форматирование. А не просто сделать "что-нибудь".

Comment: @PashaPash исправил. Только в этом вопросе меня интересует именно внедрение своей кнопки в стандартное меню (форматирование меня заинтересовало только сегодня)

Comment: Вы тут полностью скопировали содержимое какой-то статьи в описание метки. Так делать не стоит. Тем более странно выглядит текст «о которых мы поговорим чуть ниже». http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/49700

Comment: @NickVolynkin хорошо, править больше не буду.

Comment: @RussCoder: править-то можно, но перерабатывайте текст, там же есть четкие требования к описаниям меток. Можно посмотреть например [tag:android] в качестве примера. Вот тут тоже ведь скопировано? ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/39400

Comment: @NickVolynkin да. Однако я убежден в 2 вещах: 1) Если кто-то сказал уже сказал хорошо лучше хорошо повторить, чем плохо пересказать. 2) Наличие описания метки с дефектами (дефект был лишь в полном описании) несравненно лучше полного его отсутсвия.

Comment: @RussCoder: описание метки, скопированное откуда-то, это еще и нарушение авторских прав. Этого делать точно не стоит. И что хорошо для статьи-обзора, то может совсем не подходить для описания метки. У него все-таки свои задачи и свой формат.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ответ частично найден.

Надо просто создать стандартный проект - Visual Stutio Package. Выбрать Menu Command в качестве интерфейса в диалоговом окне при создании (первый вариант).
Потом открыть файл .vsct и поменять родителя у группы:

```
<Groups>
  <Group guid="guidVSPackageCmdSet" id="MyMenuGroup" priority="0x0600">
    <Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_CTXT_CODEWIN"/>
  </Group>
</Groups>
```

Именно

```
<Parent guid="guidSHLMainMenu" id="IDM_VS_CTXT_CODEWIN"/>
```

Привяжет группу (с кнопкой) в меню, появляющееся при нажатии правой кнопкой в коде. тут важен id этого меню IDM_VS_CTXT_CODEWIN и стандартный guid guidSHLMainMenu.
Можно посмотреть другие id и guid (лучше в VS - там с описанием)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/vstudio/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.vsmenus_members(v=vs.100).aspx#mainBody

В обработчике можно написать что угодно и оно заработает

```
private void MenuItemCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    MessageBox.Show("Уже что-то заработало!!!");
}
```